# visual foxpro connection string

Tags: c#, .net, connection-string, foxpro, visual-foxpro

i have to extract some data from a foxpro database.  I found a sample app that extracts data from a sql server db and stores the connection string in the app.config file in the following format -

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="test"
       connectionString="Data Source=localhost\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=test;Integrated Security=SSPI;Timeout=300;"
       providerName="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

I would like to do the same thing in foxpro, but i don't know what to put for the providerName part of the configuration.  i can get the connection string just fine.  Does anyone have any idea what the provider name would be for visual foxpro?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually ended up having to use the following for the providerName -

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection, System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
```

I am now getting the following error -

```
Specified Cast is Not Valid
```

but I am returning data, so I believe that is an unrelated issue. 
Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You'll need to download the  [VFP Provider](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=E1A87D8F-2D58-491F-A0FA-95A3289C5FD4&displaylang=en)

Then according to [connection strings](http://www.connectionstrings.com/visual-foxpro#p89) the connection string will be

```
Provider=vfpoledb;Data Source=C:\MyDbFolder\MyDbContainer.dbc;Collating Sequence=machine;
```

The provider name would be `System.Data.OleDb`

Comment: that got me further along, but now i am getting the following error - The type name 'System.Data.OleDb' could not be found for connection string.

i didn't reboot after installing the data provider, so i may try that next.